# Get text from textbox with up and down arrows in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pagination

I have a textbox in the footer of the pagination table. This textbox contains a textbox with up and down arrows as shown in the below Image. This textbox values will dynamically changed when we click on next, previous buttons.

Image URL: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC1380.jpg

**This is the input from DOM**

```
<div ng-grid-footer="" class="ng-scope"><div ng-show="showFooter" class="ngFooterPanel ng-scope ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" ng-class="{'ui-widget-content': jqueryUITheme, 'ui-corner-bottom': jqueryUITheme}" ng-style="footerStyle()" style="width: 1920px; height: 55px;">
<div class="ngTotalSelectContainer">
    <div class="ngFooterTotalItems ngNoMultiSelect" ng-class="{'ngNoMultiSelect': !multiSelect}" style="margin-top: 8px">
        <span class="ngLabel ng-binding">Total Items: 810</span><span ng-show="filterText.length > 0" class="ngLabel ng-binding ng-hide">(Showing Items: 100)</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ngFooterSelectedItems ng-hide" ng-show="multiSelect">
        <span class="ngLabel ng-binding">Selected Items: 0</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="ngPagerContainer ngNoMultiSelect" style="float: right; margin-top: 10px" ng-show="enablePaging" ng-class="{'ngNoMultiSelect': !multiSelect}">
    <div style="float:left; margin-right: 10px" class="ngRowCountPicker">
        <span style="float: left; margin-top: 8px" class="ngLabel ng-binding">Page Size:</span>
        <select style="float: left;height: 29px; width: 100px" ng-model="pagingOptions.pageSize" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
            <!-- ngRepeat: size in pagingOptions.pageSizes --><option ng-repeat="size in pagingOptions.pageSizes" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="10">10</option><!-- end ngRepeat: size in pagingOptions.pageSizes --><option ng-repeat="size in pagingOptions.pageSizes" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="25">25</option><!-- end ngRepeat: size in pagingOptions.pageSizes --><option ng-repeat="size in pagingOptions.pageSizes" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="50">50</option><!-- end ngRepeat: size in pagingOptions.pageSizes --><option ng-repeat="size in pagingOptions.pageSizes" class="ng-scope ng-binding" value="100">100</option><!-- end ngRepeat: size in pagingOptions.pageSizes -->
        </select>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left; margin-right: 10px; line-height:25px" class="ngPagerControl">
        <button class="ngPagerButton" ng-click="pageToFirst()" ng-disabled="cantPageBackward()" title="First Page"><div class="ngPagerFirstTriangle"><div class="ngPagerFirstBar"></div></div></button>
        <button class="ngPagerButton" ng-click="pageBackward()" ng-disabled="cantPageBackward()" title="Previous Page"><div class="ngPagerFirstTriangle ngPagerPrevTriangle"></div></button>

        <!--Input Textbox Which I want to Inspect -->
        <input class="ngPagerCurrent ng-valid-number ng-valid-min ng-valid ng-valid-max ng-dirty" min="1" max="9" type="number" style="width:50px; height: 26px; margin-top: 1px; padding: 0 4px" ng-model="pagingOptions.currentPage">
        <!--END-->

        <button class="ngPagerButton" ng-click="pageForward()" ng-disabled="cantPageForward()" title="Next Page"><div class="ngPagerLastTriangle ngPagerNextTriangle"></div></button>
        <button class="ngPagerButton" ng-click="pageToLast()" ng-disabled="cantPageToLast()" title="Last Page"><div class="ngPagerLastTriangle"><div class="ngPagerLastBar"></div></div></button>

        <button ng-controller="OmniSearchViewCtrl" id="page-summary-help-button" title="Help" class="ngPagerButton ng-scope" ng-click="handlePageSummaryHelpButtonClick()">
            <span class="ptipsicon ptipsicon-help" style="padding:0 6px; float:left"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
</div>
```

**This is Xpath**

```
//*[@id="PageViewContainer"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/input
```

My problem is, I am unable to get the values from the textbox since the textbox doesn't have any attribute:value. I have tried using the below lines to get the text but it just displays a blank. However, I didn't get any exceptions

```
pageNumber = findElement(By.xpath(properties.getString("PageNumber"))).getText();
pageNumber = findElement(By.xpath(properties.getString("PageNumber"))).getAttribute("value");
```

Whereas, when I tried this I am getting no such element found exception.

```
pageNumber = findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\"PageViewContainer\"]"))).getText();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what does properties.getString("PageNumber") return?

Comment: I am just getting the xpath from a properties file. Assume that there is no problem in that. Thanks

Comment: you need to inspect the element when the text is present, and show us the HTML that contains the text you wish to extract. The xpath you have given doesn't relate to the HTML snippet you have shown. There is no element with ID "PageViewContainer" shown.

Comment: Do you have other input elements with same class or ng-model? You could use By.xpath("//input[@ng-model=\"pagingOptions.currentPage\"]") if they are unique, or use with an index ([n]) if not unique

Comment: Charlie, I have inspected the element when there is a value of 2 in the text.

Comment: so show us the entire html including the text you want to find

Comment: There is no input element with of class ng-modal. I have copied and pasted the xpath here from firebug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64205/discussion-between-vikram-and-charlies).

Comment: where did you get 'class of ng-model' from? I didn't mention a 'class of ng-model'. ng-model is an attribute in the input element in your question. You have not copy pasted enough HTML. Your xpath does NOT relate to the HTML shown. Show more

Comment: I am saying about ng-model not the class, the one which you specified. Thanks :-)

Comment: I have used the xpath one you mentioned. Its not working.

Comment: Your HTML still does not contain any element with id="PageViewContainer". Your xpath needs to find such an element first. I give up, you are not helping yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//*[@id="PageViewContainer"]
```

Your xpath begins with a search for an element with an id="PageViewContainer". There is no such element in your HTML, so your xpath returns nothing.

Based on the snippet you have given, you can find the input element by:

```
//div[@class='ngPagerControl']/input
```

You can then use the getText() method to extract the text value.